# Uniform div height and button alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have three divs that need to be the same height and have a button *at* the same level, but are containing varying amounts of text above and below the button.

Right now I'm just specifying heights to compensate for how long the text might be, but if it's not that long, there's too much padding, and it still might not be high enough.

This needs to work with IE9+, and the latest chrome and firefox.  I'm starting to think the best solution is javascript unless there's a CSS miracle.  `display: flex` looked promising, but don't think it'll work with IE9

See image below.  The space between the titles and the buttons should be controlled by the longest title.  Right now it's just a hard coded height.  Similarly card heights should be controlled by the tallest card, but it's currently hard coded.

[image]

Comment: You are right. The `display:flex` option only works with IE11+. I think there are several approaches one can get to do this, I'll think about it for a moment. For now, the main question: is the place where these columns are a fixed width?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use jQuery/CSS to find the tallest of all elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781031/use-jquery-css-to-find-the-tallest-of-all-elements)

Comment: @SparoHawk (if I understand) The row isn't a fixed width, but the cards are.

Comment: I hate to say it, but perhaps the simplest way to handle it is to use a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to handle it with a `<table>` instead of divs--that way no js is required:

[**Table Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1xqquz3v/1/)

Comment: Honestly, I'd suggest using divs, but with `display:table` in the CSS. Achieves the same thing, but more flexible in the application.

Comment: @BrianBennett I like it

Comment: @MStodd Added a full answer below.

Comment: Yeah, I like that solution better. Tables make me feel dirty lol

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using `display:table` which should get you started:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">         <!-- Sets the size of the entire section -->
  <div id="row1">          <!-- Becomes your table row -->
    <div id="cell1">       <!-- Becomes the table cell -->
      <p>Information</p>
    </div>
    <div id="cell2">
      <p>A section of text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="cell3">
      <p>Some text and other stuff - even divs.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
#wrapper div {
  border:1px solid black;
}
#row1 {
  display:table;        /* Creates the table */
}
#row1 > div {
  display:table-cell;
  width:30%;            /* Sets the width of each table cell */
  height:auto;          /* Expands the height of the entire row as content is added */
}
```

Here's a **[CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/myEJGz)** with a mockup. The nice thing about this is that you can still use HTML5 and CSS3 for all of your content and styling.

Comment: The main issue is getting the buttons in the middle lined up.  That's not addressed here

Comment: Style them as divs within the cell as you would on a normal page. I don't have time at the moment to do a full workup - but within each cell, you can use normal positioning as if you were on a full page.