# Make Sub menu and Sub-Sub menu of same height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down menu with 3 Levels. What I am trying to achieve is to make the same height of SubMenu and Sub-SubMenu. Both of the menus should have the same height irrespective of items in each column(Sub Menu and Sub-Sub Menu).

Here is the HTML and CSS code which I'm using.

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #000;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#menu ul a {
  display: block;
  color: #231F20;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#menu ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#menu ul li.current {
  background: #ddd
}

#menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #4598cc;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  z-index: 5;
}

#menu ul ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

#menu ul ul a {
  color: #4598cc;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-style: 14px;
  font-family: FFMarkStdBook;
}

#menu ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#menu ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block
}

#menu>ul>li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 47px;
  position: relative;
}

#menu>ul>li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#menu>ul>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu>ul>li>ul b {
  color: #4598cc;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link One ></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link One ></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link One ></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"> Link One</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Link One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Link One</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Here is the example screenshot which I want to achieve. 
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have example in jsFiddle?

Comment: Hi @tonoslfx
Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/Codechk/q1m0kany/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To try to resolve your problem, I used jquery 'cause I could not think a pure CSS solution. So this is only a possible way.

In my solution, for every 1st level `<li>` I created a loop to get the tallest `<ul>` in it and I put the result as height of every `<ul>` in that `<li>`.

This is the script (see also this: [Use jQuery/CSS to find the tallest of all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781031/use-jquery-css-to-find-the-tallest-of-all-elements)):

```
$("#menu > ul > li").each(function(){
  var maxHeight = 0;
  var myUl=$("ul", $(this));

  myUl.each(function(){
    maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
  });

  myUl.height(maxHeight);
});
```

In your CSS, I used `visibility:visible & hidden` to get the `<ul>` height (removing your `display:none & block`).

This is all code in action. Hope it helps. :)

```js
$("#menu > ul > li").each(function(){
  var maxHeight = 0;
  var myUl=$("ul", $(this));
  
  myUl.each(function(){
    maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
  });

  myUl.height(maxHeight);
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #000;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#menu ul a {
  display: block;
  color: #231F20;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#menu ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#menu ul li.current {
  background: #ddd
}

#menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #4598cc;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  z-index: 5;
  display:block;
  visibility:hidden;
}

#menu ul ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

#menu ul ul a {
  color: #4598cc;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-style: 14px;
  font-family: FFMarkStdBook;
}

#menu ul ul ul {
  top: -1px;
  left: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#menu ul li:hover>ul {
  visibility:visible;
}

#menu>ul>li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 47px;
  position: relative;
}

#menu>ul>li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#menu>ul>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu>ul>li>ul b {
  color: #4598cc;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link One ></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link One ></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link One ></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"> Link One</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Link One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Link One</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate your efforts and it is exactly what I am looking for. Thank again mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Its the best if you restructure your html.

`.dropdown` class was added to make easier to target.

Is this what you wanted?

https://jsfiddle.net/q1m0kany/2/

```
<div id="main">
  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Link One ></a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link One ></a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link One ></a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#"> Link One</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link One</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Link One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Link One</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>


html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #000;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#menu ul a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}


#menu .dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

#menu .dropdown li {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  background-color: gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#menu .dropdown > li > a {
  font-style: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-family: FFMarkStdBook;
}

#menu .dropdown .dropdown {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#menu ul li:hover > .dropdown {
  display: block
}

#menu>ul>li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 47px;
  position: relative;
}

#menu>ul>li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#menu>ul>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu>ul>li>ul b {
  color: #4598cc;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Please look on the screenshots from user2922985!

Comment: Thanks for your help @tonoslfx, but this is not what I actually want to achieve, please refer the screenshot for more clarification. I want to make both submenu and sub-sub-menu holders with the same height with border irrespective of items. 

It seems it requires some jQuery to manage the height at runtime.