# CSS: 100% height of inner div

Tags: css

Here is working solution for Chrome and probably Firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/gHcRX/

Adding `height:100%` to all tables gives the div required data to calculate the actual `height` of parent.

But why this doesn't work in Internet Explorer and Opera...

Don't want to use javascript for this.

Is there any simple cross-browser solution?

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer we talking?

Comment: Why are you using tables for layouts? You really should be using divs.

Comment: I don't know. Had lesser problem with tables, than with divs. Probably  working completely with divs is problematic for me.

Comment: Looks like you're after [equal height columns with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns)

Comment: http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html

Comment: here is updated div issue -> http://jsfiddle.net/gHcRX/31/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should NOT be using tables for layout. It's bad practice, and will not work well across different browsers.

If all you want to achieve is getting the divs to expand 100%, you could do something like this:

```
<div style="height:300px">
    <div style="float:left;height:100%;background:green;">block1</div>
    <div style="float:left;height:100%;background:red;">block2</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gHcRX/20/

Comment: And by the way. In my example i don't have fixed height of my parent element.

Comment: I was unsure of exactly what you are trying to do, so I assumed that you simply wanted your divs to auto-expand to a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you need, using Divs instead of tables:

```
<div>
    <div style="height:300px; float: left;">
        <div style="height:100%;background:black; float: left;">block1</div>
        <div style="height:100%;background:red; float: left;">block2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Much neater

Comment: Almost my exact solution! :P You don't need the 300px height on the inner div though.

Comment: So you're trying to style an element based on the height of another (not containing element)? You either need jQuery or  the Link that Eric provided.