# How to have one column's height from the maximum of another one with CSS?

Tags: html, css, containers, tabular

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS - Equal Height Columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns)

I need to have my container with a kind of elastic height if possible, and if not I just want my menu in sidebar height, to get the same height as the video container, as it is described here:

http://clientes.ivopereira.net/nocktv/

Any ideas how to get this done? I've tried to mix the two columns (the sidebar and the video container) into one, and tried to specify a height of 100% so therefore the div left (the column left) could maximize itself as the maximum as it cans.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Come on.. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=equal+height+columns+css |||| http://www.google.fi/search?q=equal+height+columns+css&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:fi:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: This case is a little diferente, not an usual equal height column, as I have some divs inside them.

Comment: It's not different at all. You want both columns to be of equal height. Hence the equal height columns...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2114757/840973

Comment: As I said this is different. I am trying to positionate an element at the bottom of another element that is being floated left, therefore I can't use any table-cell or anything like that.

Comment: I'd like to see how you **positionate** an element...

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually achieve "equal height" columns. The closest workaround that I normally recommend to use is using the [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) technique.

However, looking more closely at your example link, it looks like you want your sidebar to be aligned to the bottom, not the top. I threw together a quick example of how you might want to achieve this effect. You can combine it with the Faux Columns technique as well. I'm assuming you have some proficiency in HTML and CSS, but feel free to ask any questions if you need help.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="sidebar">

    </div><div class="main">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container { 
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center; }
#container > div {
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block; }
.sidebar { 
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px; }
.main {
    background: blue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/8SnGS/

Comment: You might have not met Mr.Taylor in the internets http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks ( I'm referring to your "can't make actual 'equal height' columns" ) (Which also seems to be the first search result on google in my comment to the OP)

Comment: Hmm, I still stand behind what I said. If you look at http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-complete.gif, it shows that the 3 different blocks of content aren't actually 'equal heights'. It's more of a workaround to give the appearance of equal heights, not much different than the 'Faux Columns' technique in my post.

Comment: You say tomato and I say tomato. The containers are actually equal height. How do you except different a length text to all reach to the bottom? That's how text acts. The containers are infact equal height and not an illusion. Of course you stretch the text container to the bottom and not the text it self. ( It is a bit on the "heavy side", but hardly comparable to faux columns.. Even thought the initial idea is much like.. ) You can add different column colors and they're liquid columns.. Acts exactly the same as what you could achieve with javascript.

Comment: I've tried but for example, just try to add some text inside the divs, and you will get it changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use display: table and table-cell: http://jsfiddle.net/8BXGD/

Comment: As I said before, I am trying to positionate an element at the bottom of another element that is being floated left, therefore I can't use any table-cell or anything like that.

Comment: Why can't you use display table-cell? To me it sounds like a perfect fit. You get both equal height columns AND the ability to vertically align even block elements any way you like.

Comment: With table-cell is creates me a kind of margin that I really don't have. Take a look: [image 1](http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/8481/tablecell1.png) [image 2](http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/3960/tablecell2.png)

Comment: A kind of margin? Set margin to 0 then. And border-spacing.

Comment: Tried that, same result. Really can't figure out why it's moving the content a lot to the bottom.