# Tallest height matching next element

Tags: jquery

I usually use this to match elements heights:

```
function equalHeight(group) {
    tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
    }

    $(function() {
        equalHeight($('.column'));
    });
```

However, in my case I need to match elements to their nearest sibling not by class, with the following example

```
    <div class="post">
        <div class="leftCol">
            <h2>This is a post headline</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volut</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rightCol">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul>           
        </div>
    </div><!--/post-->
```

There will be multiple (over 15) instances per page of this structure. I don't want to match the height of ".leftCol" to the height of ".rightCol" across the board - that is I don't want every ".leftCol" to match every ".rightCol" on the page, just within each ".post" group - match ".leftCol" height to its immediate sibling of the ".rightCol" class... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is to set each leftCol/rightCol pair to the taller of either one, but only within the pair and you want to do the same for all pairs, you can do it like this:

```
$(".post .leftCol").each(function() {
    var $left = $(this);
    var $right = $left.next();
    var maxHeight = Math.max($left.height(), $right.height());
    $left.height(maxHeight);
    $right.height(maxHeight);
});
```

This code works as follows:

1. For each `.post .leftCol` object
2. Get the `.leftCol` jQuery object
3. Get the matching `.rightCol` jQuery object using `.next()`
4. Find out the max height between the two of them
5. Set this `.leftCol` and `.rightCol` pair each to that max height

Note: you may be able to solve this problem with CSS alone.  See [CSS - Equal Height Columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns).

Comment: perfect. you're a friend indeed, thanks man. I am now at least getting the concept mostly right but still suck on execution.