# Calculate height of absolute divs (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, height

I'm using this script http://benholland.me/javascript/how-to-build-a-site-that-works-like-pinterest/ to try and build a gallery for a website.

I'm rendering the "block" divs inside another div which has its position to relative (lets call it "block-holder").
The problem is that I cannot make the "block-holder" to wrap around these "block"s because they have position set to absolute.
My only option is to calculate the height of the highest column with JS and transfer it to a CSS class.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: There's a solution here that should work nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns

Comment: suggest you provide a demo in jsfiddle.net so problem can be seen first hand

Comment: I can't quite make it work on jsfiddle, but you'd get the idea - http://jsfiddle.net/2u9kP/ The dark div on the back has to be as tall as the highest column.