# how to inherit parent div height to its child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i do have 1 parent div and 2 child div, i want to these 2 child div will be equal to its parent height or whenever the content of 1 child div expand the other child div will expand as well. I like to use % instead of px so that when you zoom it in or out the height size stay the same or if any of you guys know some tricks to work for it i will appreciate it here's my js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/deftmagic/29Puw/4/

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="task-pane">
        <p>sample</p>
        <p>sample</p>
        <p>sample</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tbl-div">
        <p>sample</p>
        <p>sample</p>
        <p>sample</p>
        <p>sample</p>
        <p>sample</p>
        <p>sample</p>
    </div>
</div>


.content-wrapper{
background:#000;
min-height:0;
width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
    }
.task-pane{
    background:red;
    height:100%;  
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    }
.tbl-div {
    background:green;
     height:100%;
     width:80%;
    float:right;
}
```

note: guys i already search some of this same problem and it occur some do use table but my conflict to it is when i use table tag it can't provide to add div tag inside that i needed the most so please if there's any solution instead of table maybe some script i'll appreciate it-- thanks ^^

Comment: What you want is impossible without JS, unless you give the parent div a specific height (at least a percentage).

Comment: yes i do think so i hope some of you guys could provide me any thanks..

Comment: I don't want to post a link as an answer, but this article, [Fluid Width Equal Height Columns](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) has a lot of great tricks, and I think it may be useful to you, in addition to the answers posted.

Comment: @AaronBlenkush thanks for this i will try it to improve my div

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - Equal Height Columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to do this multiple times and have several tricks to pull this off, and vary depending on case. For this instance, I'd make the parent relative in size, the smaller child absolute, and the other one default so it'll cause the container to size it self.

```
.content-wrapper{
    background:#000;
    min-height:0;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.task-pane{
    background:red;
    width:20%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
}
.tbl-div {
    background:green;
    width:80%;
    float:right;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/29Puw/9/

Comment: i dont think this work same as Dream Eater answer whenever i add content div height doesnt work but thanks

Comment: i see only the left div did expand its height but the other don't. well it does some tricks i just already solve this just now its likely yours but i manipulated the parent div not the child but i guess your answer is good-- thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

```
.content-wrapper {
    background:#000;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.task-pane {
    background:red;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29Puw/6/).

Comment: i'm sorry i don't find it as a solution cause when i added some content the div size wont follow anymore.. but i appreciate it.. thanks..