# Make two columns the same height regardless of content

Tags: html, css

I have a basic grid system, really basic, which puts to 'cells' side by side in a fluid 'row'. I want the two cells to always match their height so they are equal. So if one has more content than the other, the other expands to match the height of the cell with more content.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell1">
        <div class="inner">
            <h2>Cell 1</h2>
            <p>Regardless of content, can I make Cell 1 and Cell 2 the same height so the borders are level?</p>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell2">
        <div class="inner">
            <h2>Cell 2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo of the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/QDBff/

Comment: Are the borders necessary? There is a CSS solution but it requires that you don't use borders.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a table? I know it's 'Taboo' but that is exactly what they do.

Comment: Your right, making life harder than it needs to be. Borders are essential DIV layout isn't.

Comment: Then tables it shall be

Comment: When you say cells, we get the wrong picture that you are talking about html table elements like <tr> or <td>, but instead you have <p>, <div> and <h2>. Equal height <table> cells are different matter. As for equal height columns as they are known - http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you absolutly must avoid using TABLEs, you can style your divs to behave like tables with

```
display: table;
display: table-row;
display: table-cell;
```

You can look at the markup/css and results in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aeinbu/QDBff/35/

Answer (score 2):

I made it work here with the use of jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/QDBff/10/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height1 = $('.cell1 > .inner').height();
    var height2 = $('.cell2 > .inner').height();
    if (height1 < height2) {
        $('.cell1 > .inner').height(height2);
    } else {
        $('.cell2 > .inner').height(height1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`<table><tr><td>Cel 1</td><td>Cel 2</td></tr></table>`

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your fiddle and I think it may be fixed by adding a min-height of 270px (for ex. only).

I am not a jsfiddle user, but look at my screen shot below...

[image]

Note:

You just have to tweak your min-height to fit your needs. Tweak is necessary whenever the text size increases or decreases.

But, if your content is dynamic, this is not a permanent solution.

Comment: what happens when one column exceeds min-height?

Comment: well actually it's a css based fixed and can apply on a static pages. just as i've mentioned above, on my note. when one or both cells exceeds the min height, it will be uneven again. so you have to tweak your min-height again.

Answer (score 0):

Add a large padding bottom and an equal negative margin bottom to your cells and stick `overflow: hidden` onto your row.

```
.cell {
    width: 50%;
    background: #eee;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
}

.cell:nth-child(odd) { background: #ddd; }

.row { overflow: hidden; }

.row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q9U6g/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using

`display: table`

and

`display: table-cell`

I have modified your jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Raver0124/QDBff/36/

Also another jsfiddle that i created previously - http://jsfiddle.net/jBMBR/6/

Answer (score -2):

Change the border from Inner class to Cell1 and Cell2 classes. Then give fixed height to the Cell1 and Cell2 classes.

```
.cell1 {
width: 45%;
margin-right: 1%;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
height:400px; 
}

.cell2 {
width: 45%;
margin-left: 1%;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
height:400px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/QDBff/31/

Comment: My Bad. I didn't read you question correctly. For that you can use Javascript.