# HTML: non-floating auto width navigation

Tags: html, css, css-float, autosize

I'm new to HTML & CSS and one of my first steps is creating a normal layout like

```
/----------------\
|     Header     |
|----------------|
| N  |           |
| a  |   Content |
| v  |           |
|----------------|
|   Foot         |
\----------------/
```

In order to be flexible, Navs width shouldn't be fixed and the Content should never float around it. In other words, Nav and Content should behave like table columns just that the use of tables for formatting are a big no no in HTML. My current code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Todo list</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        nav {
            float: left;
            padding-right: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            background: yellow;
            height: auto;       /* auto | inherit | 100% */
            width: auto;
        }

        #content {
             margin: 5px;
             padding-left: 5px;
        }

        header {
            background: blue;
        }

        footer {
            clear: both;
            background: #ccc;
        }

        .clearfix:after {
                content: ".";
                display: block;
                clear: both;
                visibility: hidden;
                line-height: 0;
                height: 0;
                }
        </style>
    </head> 


  <body>
    <header>
        Head
    </header>

    <nav id="main_nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact (p)</a></li> 
            <li><a href="/temp">Temp</a></li>   
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="content" class="clearfix">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <h2>A</h2><h2>C</h2><h2>D</h2>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <p>[Copyright bumf]</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which results in

[image: uglyNav]

Most solutions I found used either a fixed width for Nav or for the Content margin, which isn't a clean. It seems that [CSS Multi-column Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) or [CSS Flexible Box Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/#flex-containers) could help, but they are both "Candidate Recommendation" so I can't use them safely. What's the proper way to solve my problem?

Comment: You got a nav tag outside the body !!!. And the footer as well...and... well it must be a typo...

Comment: yes, thanks! Funny though, it didn't change anything :o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some serious issues with your markup, the `body` tag should wrap all of the page elements, the basic markup should follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- meta tags etc -->
    </head> 
    <body>
        <!-- page content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

As for the style issue, the `#content` div just needs floated to the left as well. There are other ways, but this will probably suffice.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Todo list</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        nav {
            float: left;
            padding-right: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            background: yellow;
            height: auto;       /* auto | inherit | 100% */
            width: auto;
        }

        #content {
             margin: 5px;
             padding-left: 5px;
             float: left;
        }

        header {
            background: blue;
        }

        footer {
            clear: both;
            background: #ccc;
        }
        </style>
    </head> 
<body>
    <header>
        Head
    </header>

    <nav id="main_nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact (p)</a></li> 
            <li><a href="/temp">Temp</a></li>   
        </ul>
    </nav>


        <div id="content">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <h2>A</h2><h2>C</h2><h2>D</h2>
    </div>
    <footer>
    <p>[Copyright bumf]</p>
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: now I got it: I have to float left content as well. Is there a way to get the same height as "content"?

Comment: There are a few ways to do that, you could fix the height of each with `height:300px` or remove the floats and use `table-cell` [see this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16585630/2386052)

Comment: Thank you. Is there a solution that avoids absolute values?

Comment: using `table-cell` dosen't require fixed values, [quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/4a8rY/)

Comment: I just realized that nav `width: auto;` and content `width: 100%;` collide. Changing contents width to `width: auto;` doesn't help ... but Matts `white-space: nowrap;` did!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>It is now possible in CSS3 to do the equivalent of HTML-based table layouts using pure CSS alone.</strike> (see comment).

Pure CSS equivalents for HTML-based table layouts have been in the CSS spec since version 2.1. They are now supported well in most browsers. [Here is a good article on this.](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/tables/)

Support for IE7 and below [is limited](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

Answer (score 2):

> Nav and Content should behave like table columns

If you meant this literally, you could use the table layout model (as [mentioned by Holf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598824/3625)).

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/gist/library/pure/5595880/) or the following code:

```css
nav {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background: yellow;
    white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent nav from ever inserting line breaks between words (like before "(p)"). */
}

#content {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 100%; /* Because of table layout, this will shrink nav to the smallest width its content can handle (similarly to how float widths work). */
}

header {
    background: blue;
}

#main {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

footer {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<header>
    Head
</header>

<div id="main">
    <nav id="main_nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact (p)</a></li> 
            <li><a href="/temp">Temp</a></li>   
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="content" class="clearfix">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <h2>A</h2><h2>C</h2><h2>D</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <p>[Copyright bumf]</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/9YnsT/)

HTML:

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="nav">
    <div class="wrapper">Nav</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="wrapper">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
html, body{height:100%; margin:0; padding: 0; background:#ccc;}
#header{ background: #0cc; height:50px; position: absolute; width:100%;}
#main, #content, #nav{ width:100%; height:100%;}
#content{ background: #555; width:75%; float:left;}
#nav{ background: transparent; width:25%; float:left;}
.wrapper{padding: 50px 15px;}
#footer{background: #fcc;  height: 50px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%;}
</style>
```

Comment: this looks nice, too. Just the Nav bar goes further than the footer, my initial approach to fix it with `height: 100%-50px` failed :(

Answer (score 0):

Well you need a better understanding of `<div>` tags and the three positioning schemes - relative, absolute and fixed.

I have taken the liberty of editing your code my style, although it does not include the positioning.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <style type="text/css">
    body,
    html {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        color:#000;
        background:#a7a09a;
    }
    #wrap {
        width:750px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background:#99c;
    }
    #header {
        padding:5px 10px;
        background:#ddd;
    }
    h1 {
        margin:0;
    }
    #nav {
        padding:5px 10px;
        background:grey;
    }
    #nav ul {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
    }
    #nav li {
        display:inline;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    #sidebar {
        float:left;
        width:230px;
        padding:10px;
        background:yellow;
        height:100%;
    }
    h2 {
        margin:0 0 1em;
    }
    #main {
        float:right;
        width:480px;
        padding:10px;
        background:red;
    }
    #footer {
        clear:both;
        padding:5px 10px;
        background:#cc9;
    }
    #footer p {
        margin:0;
    }
    * html #footer {
        height:1px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header"><h1>header goes here</h1></div>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Options</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <h2>Siidebar</h2>
        <p><a href="/">Home</a></p>
        <p><a href="/">Content</a></p>
        <p><a href="/">Content</a></p>
        <p><a href="/">Content</a></p></div>

    <div id="main">
        <h2>Main Content</h2>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Link 3</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need a better understanding of English grammar, spelling and punctuation.  I have taken the opportunity to edit your Answer to improve it.  (Spot the irony here?)

Comment: well, i always agree with you people. i am bad at english and worse at punctuatrions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page i think it will solve your problem.

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/html-layout.php

Comment: their solution uses a fixed width (width:120px). I tried to avoid that.