# Navigation column tall as Content one: maybe with calc()?

Tags: css, layout

I have classical 2 columns layout, but I have constrained about NAVIGATION and CONTENT blocks are both floated left (side-by-side). Below them there is FOOTER block that spans across entire windows width and is floated left too, but below others divs.

Obviously CONTENT has an auto height based on its content, but I wish that NAVIGATION has an equal height.

I was investigating about

> calc()

property that seems very promising, but.... I was not avble to reach my objective.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not enough points to comment your post…

I think your answer is here:
[CSS - Equal Height Columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns)