# left and right div's height is not increasing when the content of center div is increased

Tags: html, css

Left and right div's height is not increasing when the content of center div is increased. I want the left and and right div also increased when the content overflows its height.

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

<head>

<style>


.header
{
background-color:grey;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;
height:100px;
width:97%;
border:2px dotted green;
display:table;
}


.left
{clear:both;
background-color:grey;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:10px;
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
height:100%;
width:10%;
display:table;
border:2px dotted green;

}


.center
{
background-color:grey;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-left:10px;
float:left;
height:100%;
width:75%;
display:table;
border:2px dotted green;
}

.right
{
background-color:grey;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-left:10px;
float:right;
height:100%;
width:10%;
display:table;
border:2px dotted green;
}



.footer
{
background-color:white;
border:2px dotted green;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;
height:50px;
width:97%;
display:table;
}



</style>

<title> Login </title>

</head>

<body text="black">


<div class="header">
HEADER

</div>


<div class="container">
<div class="left">
home<br>
profile<br>
services<br>

</div>

<div class="center">



What is HTML

HTML is an acronym which stands for Hyper Text Mark Up Language. Let's see what is Hyper Text and what is Mark Up Language?

Hyper Text: Hyper Text simply means "Text within Text". A text has a link within it, is a hypertext. Every time when you click on a word which brings you to a new webpage, you have clicked on a hypertext.

Markup language: A markup language is a programming language that is used make text more interactive and dynamic. It can turn a text into images, tables, links etc.
The word Markup refers to the symbol or Sequence of characters added to the ordinary text to define the structure of the text. It can also specify links to other documents.

An HTML document is made of many HTML tags and each HTML tag contains different content.
HTML is an acronym which stands for Hyper Text Mark Up Language. Let's see what is Hyper Text and what is Mark Up Language?

  <p>  Hyper Text: Hyper Text simply means "Text within Text". A text has a link within it, is a hypertext. Every time when you click on a word which brings you to a new webpage, you have clicked on a hypertext.</p>

 <p>   Markup language: A markup language is a programming language that is used make text more interactive and dynamic. It can turn a text into images, tables, links etc.</p>
The word Markup refers to the symbol or Sequence of characters added to the ordinary text to define the structure of the text. It can also specify links to other documents.

   <p> An HTML document is made of many HTML tags and each HTML tag contains di

HTML is an acronym which stands for Hyper Text Mark Up Language. Let's see what is Hyper Text and what is Mark Up Language?</p>

Hyper Text: Hyper Text simply means "Text within Text". A text has a link within it, is a hypertext. Every time when you click on a word which brings you to a new webpage, you have clicked on a hypertext.

Markup language: A markup language is a programming language that is used make text more interactive and dynamic. It can turn a text into images, tables, links etc.
The word Markup refers to the symbol or Sequence of characters added to the ordinary text to define the structure of the text. It can also specify links to other documents.

An HTML document is made of many HTML tags and each HTML tag contains di

HTML is an acronym which stands for Hyper Text Mark Up Language. Let's see what is Hyper Text and what is Mark Up Language?

Hyper Text: Hyper Text simply means "Text within Text". A text has a link within it, is a hypertext. Every time when you click on a word which brings you to a new webpage, you have clicked on a hypertext.

Markup language: A markup language is a programming language that is used make text more interactive and dynamic. It can turn a text into images, tables, links etc.
The word Markup refers to the symbol or Sequence of characters added to the ordinary text to define the structure of the text. It can also specify links to other documents.

An HTML document is made of many HTML tags and each HTML tag contains di

HTML is an acronym which stands for Hyper Text Mark Up Language. Let's see what is Hyper Text and what is Mark Up Language?

Hyper Text: Hyper Text simply means "Text within Text". A text has a link within it, is a hypertext. Every time when you click on a word which brings you to a new webpage, you have clicked on a hypertext.

Markup language: A markup language is a programming language that is used make text more interactive and dynamic. It can turn a text into images, tables, links etc.
The word Markup refers to the symbol or Sequence of characters added to the ordinary text to define the structure of the text. It can also specify links to other documents.

An HTML document is made of many HTML tags and each HTML tag contains di


HTML is an acronym which stands for Hyper Text Mark Up Language. Let's see what is Hyper Text and what is Mark Up Language?

Hyper Text: Hyper Text simply means "Text within Text". A text has a link within it, is a hypertext. Every time when you click on a word which brings you to a new webpage, you have clicked on a hypertext.

Markup language: A markup language is a programming language that is used make text more interactive and dynamic. It can turn a text into images, tables, links etc.
The word Markup refers to the symbol or Sequence of characters added to the ordinary text to define the structure of the text. It can also specify links to other documents.

An HTML document is made of many HTML tags and each HTML tag contains di

HTML is an acronym which stands for Hyper Text Mark Up Language. Let's see what is Hyper Text and what is Mark Up Language?

Hyper Text: Hyper Text simply means "Text within Text". A text has a link within it, is a hypertext. Every time when you click on a word which brings you to a new webpage, you have clicked on a hypertext.

Markup language: A markup language is a programming language that is used make text more interactive and dynamic. It can turn a text into images, tables, links etc.
The word Markup refers to the symbol or Sequence of characters added to the ordinary text to define the structure of the text. It can also specify links to other documents.

An HTML document is made of many HTML tags and each HTML tag contains di

HTML is an acronym which stands for Hyper Text Mark Up Language. Let's see what is Hyper Text and what is Mark Up Language?

Hyper Text: Hyper Text simply means "Text within Text". A text has a link within it, is a hypertext. Every time when you click on a word which brings you to a new webpage, you have clicked on a hypertext.

Markup language: A markup language is a programming language that is used make text more interactive and dynamic. It can turn a text into images, tables, links etc.
The word Markup refers to the symbol or Sequence of characters added to the ordinary text to define the structure of the text. It can also specify links to other documents.

An HTML document is made of many HTML tags and each HTML tag contains di


</div>

<div class="right">
RIGHT
</div>


</div><div class="footer">
Footer
</footer>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And what is wrong with the various approaches that can be found e.g. [CSS - Equal Height Columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns) or [CSS Tricks: Fluid Width Equal Height Columns](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `display:table-cell` on left, center, right div. And you cannot use `FLOAT` with display property. With Float display won't work. So remove `float:left` from all around.

No need to put `height:100%` on left, center, right divs. `height:100%` works only with the outermost div which is just inside the body.

Comment: If you use the :after {clear: both} hack I think you can use the float property to not break out of the parent.

Comment: No. Float and clearing the float are different from the problem. Increasing one div's height on the basis of another div's height needs a structure equilient to table-cell and there is only one property display:table-cell inside display:table. And from display and float, float have the previledge to perform the element's alignment. So cannot put float with it.

Comment: Thank you Aabha and Adil

Answer (score 0):

I think you got your `display: table` and `display: table-cell` styles confused. `table-cell`s should be contained within `table`s which means you should give you `.container` class a display of `table` and the `.left, .center, .right` a display of `table-cell`. Figuring out the margins/paddings to give yourself the gap between elements, as you seem to want to do, may require nesting a set of `div`s within your elements with display properties of `block` or `inline-block` to give you the ability to add margins/paddings.

Here is a quick markup you should use as a starting point.

http://codepen.io/dustinpoissant/pen/bNRYwr?editors=110

#### HTML

```
<header>
  <h2>Header</h2>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <p>home<br>
    profile<br>
    services</p>
  </div><!-- .left -->
  <div class="center">
    <h2>What is HTML</h2>
    <p>HTML is an acronym which stands for Hyper Text Mark Up Language. Let's see what is Hyper Text and what is Mark Up Language?</p>
    <p>Hyper Text: Hyper Text simply means "Text within Text". A text has a link within it, is a hypertext. Every time when you click on a word which brings you to a new webpage, you have clicked on a hypertext.</p>
    <p>Markup language: A markup language is a programming language that is used make text more interactive and dynamic. It can turn a text into images, tables, links etc.</p>
    <p>The word Markup refers to the symbol or Sequence of characters added to the ordinary text to define the structure of the text. It can also specify links to other documents.</p>
    <p>An HTML document is made of many HTML tags and each HTML tag contains different content.</p>
    <p>HTML is an acronym which stands for Hyper Text Mark Up Language. Let's see what is Hyper Text and what is Mark Up Language?</p>
    <p>Hyper Text: Hyper Text simply means "Text within Text". A text has a link within it, is a hypertext. Every time when you click on a word which brings you to a new webpage, you have clicked on a hypertext.</p>
    <p>Markup language: A markup language is a programming language that is used make text more interactive and dynamic. It can turn a text into images, tables, links etc.</p>
    <p>The word Markup refers to the symbol or Sequence of characters added to the ordinary text to define the structure of the text. It can also specify links to other documents.</p>
    <p>An HTML document is made of many HTML tags and each HTML tag contains... </p>
  </div><!-- .center -->
  <div class="right">
    <p>RIGHT</p>
  </div><!-- .right -->
</div><!-- .container -->
<footer>
  <p>FOOTER</p>
</footer>
```

#### CSS

```
header {
  display: block;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px dotted green;
}
.container {
  display: table;
}
.left, .right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 2px dotted green;
  background-color: grey;
}
.center {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 2px dotted green;
  background-color: grey;
}
footer {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  border:2px dotted green;
  height:50px;
}
```

I hope this helps you understand the use of `display: table;` vs `display: table-cell;`

Another answer might be to use an actual `<table>`.

Or you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".center").on("resize", function(){
    $(".left, .right").height( $(".center").height() );
  });
});
```

This will force the sides to always match the height of the center. The disadvantage of this approach is when the sides are taller than the center the sides heights will, as expected, still match the height of the center causing an overflow.