# CSS, html two columns auto length

Tags: html, css

How do I make those columns to be same width? Not the fix way. I want to do it automatically. It means when one will contain more text it will be longer so the second one will be equally long.
CSS

```
    article.leftnews {
    float: left;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 43%;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    overflow: auto;
    border:5px solid #0000CC;
}
article.rightnews {
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-left: 52%;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    overflow: auto;
    border:5px solid #000066;
}
section{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 700px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

[My demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/fvypskkg/)

Comment: Are you saying you want these columns to always have equal heights? Also, this part of your question seems very contradictory to me: ``when one will contain more text it will be longer but the second one will be as long as the first one``. Judging by the first half of this excerpt I would assume you mean that the columns can have different heights. But after reading the second part, it sounds like that is not the case.

Comment: Also, when talking about dimensions in css, try to use the words ``width`` and ``height`` only

Comment: sry for my english :) ... Yeah i want them to be aqual.

Comment: I *think* this is a duplicate of (and closed the question as such, but then I re-read the question and discovered I don't really understand what's being asked for): http://stackoverflow.com/q/2114757/82548

Answer (score 1):

The best way to me is using CSS `table` and `table-cell`

http://jsfiddle.net/2d9917o7/

**Update:** for rounded corners style, additional `<div>` inside each table cell is needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/2d9917o7/1/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <article class="leftnews">left<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>end</article>
    <article class="rightnews">right</article>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.leftnews,
.rightnews {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    background: pink;
}

.leftnews {
    background: lime;
}
```

Comment: i know it could be good ...but i cant use table. Tables are for "table things".

Comment: @TomP Since there is no elegant way to do what you want to do with pure CSS, you are going to have to do 'Table Things' to get it to work.  Either that or change your layout.  This is the best way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @TomP as you can see, it's not using `<table>` as markups.