# CSS two column layout using float resulting in unequal heights of columns

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="header">
        <h1>header</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <p>Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis. In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis viverra. Nulla fringilla, orci ac euismod semper, magna diam porttitor mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien justo in libero. Vestibulum mollis mauris enim. Morbi euismod magna ac lorem rutrum elementum. Donec viverra auctor lobortis. Pellentesque eu est a nulla placerat dignissim. Morbi a enim in magna semper bibendum.</p>
        <p>Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis. In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis viverra. Nulla fringilla, orci ac euismod semper, magna diam porttitor mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien justo in libero. Vestibulum mollis mauris enim. Morbi euismod magna ac lorem rutrum elementum. Donec viverra auctor lobortis. Pellentesque eu est a nulla placerat dignissim. Morbi a enim in magna semper bibendum.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="navigation">
        <a href="#">Nav item</a>
        <a href="#">Nav item</a>
        <a href="#">Nav item</a>
        <a href="#">Nav item</a>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    font: 100% calibri;
}

#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: pink;
}

#content {
    float:left;
    width: 660px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#navigation {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

#navigation a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #aaa;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Result:
https://jsfiddle.net/x83uw77a/

How do I get both columns to have equal heights?

Comment: This is a common question with [several solutions](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/), from [flex-box](http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback) to [displaying as a table](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-equal-height/). Also check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use display:table, and display:table-cell, instead of floats.

Wrap your content in one 'container div':

```
<div id="content-holder">
        <div id="content">
            <p>Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis. In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis viverra. Nulla fringilla, orci ac euismod semper, magna diam porttitor mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien justo in libero. Vestibulum mollis mauris enim. Morbi euismod magna ac lorem rutrum elementum. Donec viverra auctor lobortis. Pellentesque eu est a nulla placerat dignissim. Morbi a enim in magna semper bibendum.</p>
            <p>Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis. In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis viverra. Nulla fringilla, orci ac euismod semper, magna diam porttitor mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien justo in libero. Vestibulum mollis mauris enim. Morbi euismod magna ac lorem rutrum elementum. Donec viverra auctor lobortis. Pellentesque eu est a nulla placerat dignissim. Morbi a enim in magna semper bibendum.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="navigation">
            <a href="#">Nav item</a>
            <a href="#">Nav item</a>
            <a href="#">Nav item</a>
            <a href="#">Nav item</a>
        </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#content-holder {
display:table;
}
#content {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 660px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#navigation {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/x83uw77a/1/

Comment: Thanks but I need to be as backward compatible as possible with older browsers that do not support the `display: table-cell` option.

Comment: @RobertRocha, is javascript/jquery allowed? This is my last idea, in case that you need to support IE7 and IE8...

Comment: Yes JavaScript is allowed. The website will be used with old computers running Windows XP that use either IE 6 or IE 7.

Comment: I do like your solution though and will keep it in mind when developing for mode modern systems.

Comment: Well, thanks...regarding js/jquery workaround for older browsers: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+equal+heights&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=TtnLVbvJEsL2aIavsbAF I am sure you will find something here...

Comment: Or simple one-liner: $('#navigation').css('height',$('#content').height()+'px'); https://jsfiddle.net/x83uw77a/2/ (The plugins,a s far as i know, calculate height of tallest div in block, and set the rest accordingly, but you can use this, i guess...)

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be defining both the *#navigation* and the *#content* **height** with a reasonable size, per se **height: 960px;** and giving them both **overflow: auto;** which will create a scroll bar when the child elements overflow past the parent. Good **IE 4** support.

**CSS:**

```css
    #navigation,
    #content {
        overflow: auto; /* IE 4 SUPPORT */
        height: 960px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can make it work, you can use position: absolute and height: 100%

```
#navigation {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 660px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

You can then change the height of #container accordingly to get the height you want for both columns!

If you don't need the backwards compatibility, try using flex-box as a more modern approach!