# Column of same height with responsive image inside

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, height, multiple-columns

I'm working on a website and most of my page have this structure :

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-1-2">
  <img>
 </div>
 <div class="col-2-2">
  <p>Text</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

I would like that the image of the first column was at the same height as the text in the second column.

Does anybody knows how can I do that ?

Thanks in advance ;)

P.S : sorry for the bad english

Comment: I suppose you are using some kind of CSS Framework, Bootstrap or Foundation ? Take a look at these: [Bootstrap equal height columns](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/), [Foundation equal height columns](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/equalizer.html), [Fluid width equal height columns](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)

Comment: No I used this website : http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/calculator/

Comment: Check this out then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns

Comment: Thank you muhammet, the flex solution works fine. My problem now is that I would like the image to occupy all the height of the column. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: You are welcome! Try adding `align-items: stretch;` to `img`.

Answer (score 0):

you would have to set the image container as absolute and the row as relative and then set width as 50% to the column container and a height of 100%. the img should have max-width: 100% as a css property

Comment: When you say the image container, you mean the class="col-1-2" ?

Comment: yes the col-1-2 which has the image