# How to make a dynamic-height DIV

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I have a `float: left` siderbar `<div>` that has `min-height` set to `500px`.

The content area `<div>` to the left of it also has `min-height` of `500px`.

What I can't seem to figure out is this: if the height of the content `<div>` goes **over** 500px due to longer page content, how do I get the sidebar `<div>` to grow downward pixel-for-pixel, matching the height of the content `<div>`, so that it is still touching the footer `<div>` that is below both of those (it uses `clear: both`)?

I *could* use a table to do this, but I'd really rather find the CSS to do it more... "properly."

The current CSS for the content, sidebar, and footer `<div>`'s:

```
#ContentHolder
{
    float:left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 590px;
    min-height: 500px;
}

#SideBar
{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    border-top: 2px solid #404040;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    background-image: url('Images/SideBar.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom;
}

#Footer
{
    clear: both;
    background: #404040;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #707070;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #202020;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are searching for `FlexBox`

Here we go: [CSS - Equal Height Columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns)

I hope I helped ya,
good luck.

Comment: Beautiful!  I had no idea this existed.  Just added a DIV around the two columns with css of the DIV set to display: flex.

Answer (score 0):

You just need some simple CSS, have two columns, set their width,float one side or the other, and then having a div tag to clear these columns will make sure anything that appears after that, gets rendered below.

```
.clr {
  clear: both;
}

.column1 {
  width: 500px;
}

.column2 {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
}

<div class="column1">
no matter how big this, does nto matter
</div>

<div class="column2">
this does not matter
</div>

<div class="clr"></div>

<div class="footer">
This is my footer
</div>
```