# How to make pane extend to the bottom of its container

Tags: html, css

I have a site with two columns, a content one and a menu one. The menu is fairly large and will sometimes be taller than the content pane. I basically have the following setup at the moment:

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    background: red;
}
#first {
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}
#second {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
#clear {
    clear: both;
}
a {
    color: white;
}
* {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div id="first">Some content</div>
    <div id="second">Menu<br>Menu<br>Menu<br>Menu<br>Menu<br>Menu</div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The `#first` div doesn't reach the bottom of the container, even when I add `height: 100%;`. How can I fix this?

Comment: There are plenty of ways, see [CSS - Equal Height Columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns)

Comment: @Pangloss So very right .. voted to close as dupe

Answer (score 1):

You need a height on its parents all the way to the html/body tags

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
}
#first {
  flex: 1;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#second {
  flex: 1;
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
a {
  color: white;
}
* {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
    <div class='container'>
        <div id="first">Some content</div>
        <div id="second">Menu</div>
    </div>
```

For older browsers...`display: table`

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
}
#first {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#second {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
a {
  color: white;
}
* {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
        <div id="first">Some content</div>
        <div id="second">Menu</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Umm... I don't think it is working :|

Comment: @JAtkin What you mean when you say it is not working?

Comment: The `some content` pane is supposed to reach down to the end of the menu pane, and possibly further based on the content.

Comment: @LGSon when the viewport height is smaller than 300px.

Comment: Oh, hehe ;) Thanks @Pangloss! That explains it.

Comment: @JAtkin Updated using `flex` instead ... much better solution, will that work for you? ...If no, I will add a `display: table` too

Comment: Probably, I'll need to try later. (BTW, I have no idea how HTML and CSS code work, I'm just playing with some example code I found, so that's why I sound clueless ;)

Comment: @JAtkin I added the `display: table` too

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flexbox`

```css
.container {
width: 300px;
margin: auto;
background: red;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
}
#first {
width: 75%;
float: left;
background-color: blue;
}
#second {
width: 25%;
float: left;
background-color: green;
color: white;
}
#clear {
clear: both;
}
a {
color: white;
}
* {
color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div id="first">Some content</div>
<div id="second">Menu<br>Menu<br>Menu<br>Menu<br>Menu<br>Menu</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the container an height because if not `#first` will be 100% of how what if the parent don't have a height the child can not be 100% of it!!

Maybe you give him 300px like the `#second` or less and then you give `#first` 100% and it will work