# CSS alignment issue when title is too long in a list loading with Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a list loading with AngualarJS ng repeat. List contains images and title, like that. This is the code for the list.

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="data in allStars">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <a style="color: black" class="thumbnail" href="#/star/{{data.psid}}">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="lib/{{data.imagepath}}"
                     alt="">
                <div class="row thumbEffect">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        {{data.psname}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        Views : {{data.views}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        Scenes : {{data.scenes}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is loading nicely in desktop versions. But in mobile versions, when the title is too long, it comes to two lines and so the image below that getting a big space. But I want to make it look as following image. When title getting long, other side images also getting same height. (There are two images in my site too in mobile view).

[image]

How can I do this ? With CSS and Javascript ?

Comment: Can you share a fidler??

Comment: Yes, use Flexbox's magic for that...

Comment: Where's your CSS code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - Equal Height Columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns)

Comment: @ShakirAhamed This is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/chanu1993/p53xhe0L/  And try to small the size of the result page. And see, when the name is too long, the bottom image goes to far down. Want to stop that