# How to get boxes, one at a side of the other, of the same size using <li>?

Tags: html, css

I using Download Monitor Wordpress plugin to get download boxes, made of `<li>` one at the side of the other, but the box size depends of the amount of text an imga size. How can I make boxes of the same size?

https://jsfiddle.net/rodrick26/24z9q8b1/

I think this is the important CSS part:

```
.dlm-downloads li {
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}

.content ul {
    list-style: disc;
}

.download-box {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1em auto;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.1), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}

.download-box img.wp-post-image {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - Equal Height Columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns)

Comment: When posting, please include the *minimum* amount of code necessary to show your problem, *in the question itself*. See [mcve]. CSS is pretty meaningless without the HTML to which it applies.