# JQuery - How to dynamically set height of one div equal to that of another

Tags: jquery, css

I have two divs, `.box-1` and `.box-2`.

I want to set the height of both to be equal to whichever has the greater height.

Can anyone tell me why this code doesn't work?

```
var $box1Height = $('.box-1').height();
var $box2Height = $('.box-2').height();

if ($box2Height > $box1Height) {
    ($box1Height).height($box2Height)
} else {
    ($box2Height).height($box1Height)
}
```

Comment: Why don't use CSS for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns

Comment: Try getting rid of the paranthesis around '($box1Height)' and '($box2Height)'.

Comment: @PoulBak those don't matter (unless for code style)

Comment: There is a bug in my previous comment. Missing "you".

Answer (score 2):

The elements that you want to update are `$(".box-1")` and `$(".box-2")`. Instead of update them, you took theirs height value, and tried to update their height value's height value (something like that: `$(".box-1").height().height(new_value);`, which obviously doesn't exist. The compare was good, but the update wasn't for the right elements.

Instead of taking `$('.box-1').height();`, you can take only the element `$('.box-1')` and work with it.

Like this:

```
var box1 = $('.box-1');
var box2 = $('.box-2');
```

Now that we have the element itself, let's work with it's attributes. To get the height of the element- use:

```
box1.height();
```

To set new value to this `height` property, use:

```
box1.height(new_value);
```

Put it all together:

```
var box1 = $('.box-1');
var box2 = $('.box-2');
if (box1.height() > box2.height()) {
    box1.height(box2.height())
} else {
    box2.height(box1.height())
}
```

Comment: I would add an explanation explaining why this works, even though it's fairly obvious (he was updating variable values rather than DOM element attributes).

Comment: @JoshuaMcNabb explanation inserted :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the largest height of the two by using [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), removing the need for an if statement. Then just set both box heights to the result of `.max()`

```
var maxHeight = Math.max(box1.height(), box2.height())
box1.height(maxHeight)
box2.height(maxHeight)
```

Below is a working example

```js
$(function() {
  // cache the box selectors
  var box1 = $('.box1')
  var box2 = $('.box2')
  
  // determine which box is taller
  var maxHeight = Math.max(box1.height(), box2.height())
  
  // apply the tallest height to both
  box1.height(maxHeight)
  box2.height(maxHeight)
})
```

```css
.box1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.box2 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1">box1</div>
<div class="box2">box2</div>
```