# CSS two horizontal divs equal height

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
   <div>
     hello1
   </div>
   <div>
     hello2
   </div>
</div>
```

I want the two inner `div`'s to take/fill up the whole space of the outer `div` (height/vertically). But both inner `div`'s should have the equal height

Comment: Take a look at Flexbox. This website should give you enough information to figure out how https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns

Comment: When they both take up the space, which child div should be in front of the other?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS' `flexbox`, see my example below:

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
}

.col {
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
     hello1
   </div>
   <div class="col">
     hello2<br>
     same height!
   </div>
</div>
```